# Как сделать свой редактор свойств?

Tags: delphi, ооп

Допустим дополняем **Frame** свойством: **_Type**.

```
TType = (type_a, type_b, type_c);

TMyFrame = Class(TFrame)
Private
  FType: TType;
Published
  Property _Type: TType Read FType Write FType;
End;
```

Нужно к нему написать редактор свойства, чтобы был выпадающий список, например:

```
type a
type b
type c
```

для каждого выбранного типа имеем класс:

```
TClassA = Class
  StrA1: String;
  StrA2: String;
End;

TClassB = Class
  IntB1: Integer;
  IntB2: Integer;
End;

TClassC = Class
  StrC1: String;
  IntC2: Integer;
End;
```

Нужно, чтобы при выборе из выпадающего списка нужного типа, открывались плюсом свойства соответствующего класса (количество их может быть разным).

Накидаем редактор свойств:

```
  TFrameTypeEditor = Class(TClassProperty)
  Public
    Function GetAttributes: TPropertyAttributes; Override;
    Procedure SetValue(Const Value: String); Override;
    Procedure GetValues(Proc: TGetStrProc); Override;
    Procedure GetProperties(Proc: TGetPropProc); Override;
  End;

implementation

{ TFrameTypeEditor }

Function TFrameTypeEditor.GetAttributes: TPropertyAttributes;
Begin //чтобы можно было вернуть свой список
  Result := [paValueList, paSortList{, paSubProperties}]; 
  //На счёт paSubProperties так и не понял надо ли оно?
  //По идее стандартные должны из класса автоматом перениматься?
  //Но где? в SetValue?
End;

Procedure TFrameTypeEditor.GetProperties(Proc: TGetPropProc);
Begin
  Inherited;
  //
End;

Procedure TFrameTypeEditor.GetValues(Proc: TGetStrProc);
Begin
  Inherited;
  //создадим наш список типов
  //по идее перечисляемый тип и так будет выпадать, но хотелось бы
  //строки  локализировать, а если мы их добавляем, они дублируются :(
  //Их надо бы не добавить, а изменить. А если мы их изменяем, они при
  //выборе не соответствуют типу! Надо, видимо, это в SetValues подгонять?
  Proc('type a');
  Proc('type b');
  Proc('type c');
End;

Procedure TFrameTypeEditor.SetValue(Const Value: String);
Begin
  Inherited;
  //
End;

//Ну и регистрируем всё это дело
Procedure Register;
Begin
  RegisterPropertyEditor(TypeInfo(TType), TMyFrame , '_Type', TFrameTypeEditor);
  RegisterComponents('MyFramesPalette', [TMyFrame]);
End;
```

Вопросы:

1. От какого редактора лучше для данной цели наследоваться?
2. Как/где присваивать класс, соответствующий выбранному типу?
3. Нужно ли использовать GetProperties или они таки должны перениматься автоматом при присвоении класса?

в общем, как это лучше допилить, подскажите.